# How to verify user input using Javascript add Event Listener?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the user to enter the correct sum and verify that. On completion of verification it will bring a text file.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend style="font-size: 30px; color: red;">Verification table</legend>
    <form>
        <label>The sum of 7 + 2 : </label> <input type="number" id="inputNumberBox" />
        <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" onsubmit="myFunction()">Hit me Baby!!
        </button>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

```
function myFunction() {
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("inputNumberBox").value;

    function checkValidation() {
        if (inputValue == 9) {
            var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
            client.open('GET', '/testText.txt');
            client.onreadystatechange = function() {
                alert(client.responseText);
            }
            client.send();
        } else {
            window.alert("Try again");
        }
    }
    clickButton.addEventListener("click", checkValidation, false);
}
```

Comment: Start by neatly indenting your code with spaces.

Comment: Can you format your code. Also why are the functions nested ?

Comment: What the main question is: how to verify or how to load a file?

Comment: @vmaksym First I want to verify user input and then if the verification goes through I want open this text file.

Answer (score 0):

you have a lot of unnecessary functions which are not even called, you can remove your `checkValidation()` and `readText()` and the code inside them can be present as they are, see below what I mean -

```
function myFunction() {
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("inputNumberBox").value;
  var clickButton = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
  if (inputValue == 9) {
    // enter your code for getting the text file
  } else {
    window.alert("Try again");
  }
}
```

also in your `html`, you have already defined the event listener, `onsubmit` `myFunction()` is called, so the last line of you JS code is unnecessary again.
See the working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/udwn5t9y/).

Comment: Can you check now? I do not know how to call a local file.

Comment: @EvaStuart I think this might be helpful for you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file